# Plotting asymmetric error bars with a multi-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am attempting to use the pandas DataFrame.plot(kind='bar') function to add error bars when I have a multiindex in the MxN DataFrame.

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html#visualization-errorbars), this is possible by providing the `yerr` argument with an Mx2xN array, but I have had no luck in using a DataFrame for this argument. Using a DataFrame for the error bars (the same shape as the data, but with 2 columns for high and low bounds) would of course be very convenient, because it would allow the index itself to match up with the data.

As it stands, I have only been able to get it working by bludgeoning the columns of high/low bounds into an Mx2xN numpy array using the rather brutal tools of newaxis and append. This is fraught with error, and unsightly in syntax, so my question is: is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do without having to hammer a DataFrame into an array as I have done here?

DataFrame to plot (code to generate at bottom of post):

```
> print data
       errlo    errhi     mean     
letter     a  b     a   b    a    b
word                               
bar        7  5    12  11  9.5  8.0
foo        5  6    11   9  8.0  7.5
```

Desired plotting code:

```
> data['mean'].plot(kind='bar', yerr=data['errlo','errhi'])
```

Actual plotting code - this is what I'm hoping can be improved upon:

```
> errlo     = data['mean'] - data['errlo']
> errhi     = data['errhi'] - data['mean']
> errlo_arr = errlo.values[:,np.newaxis,:]
> errhi_arr = errhi.values[:,np.newaxis,:]
> yerr      = np.append(errlo_arr, errhi_arr, axis=1).T
> data['mean'].plot(kind='bar', yerr=yerr)
```

Desired Output:
[image: Bar plot of dataframe with multi-indexed columns, with error bars]

Code to generate the DataFrame:

```
> ix3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar']], names=['letter', 'word'])
> df3 = pd.DataFrame({'data1': [3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2], 'data2': [6, 5, 7, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5]}, index=ix3)
> df=df3.groupby(level=['letter','word']).sum()
> df.columns=['errlo','errhi']
> df['mean']=df.mean(axis='columns')
> data=df.unstack(level='letter')
> print data
       errlo    errhi     mean     
letter     a  b     a   b    a    b
word                               
bar        7  5    12  11  9.5  8.0
foo        5  6    11   9  8.0  7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the columns directly and avoid your `numpy` code by doing:

```
#assuming your initial frame
df =df3.groupby(level=['letter','word']).sum()
df.columns=['errlo','errhi']
df['mean']=df.mean(axis='columns')


df['errlo']  = df['mean'] - df['errlo']
df['errhi']  = df['errhi'] - df['mean']

data=df.unstack(level='letter')

data['mean'].plot(kind='bar', yerr=data[['errlo','errhi']].T.values)
```

returns:

[image]